# How to get all numbered keys in object (and find lower and higher keys)

Tags: javascript, object

I have an object with mixed keys names - strings and digits:

```
var obj = {
  foo: 'foo val',
  bar1: 'bar1 val',
  1: 'one',
  2: 'two',
  99: 'ninety nine',
  1024: 'one thousand and twenty four'
};
```

I want know few things about this object:

1. Get list of all numbered keys (how to drop-off `bar1` and `foo`;
2. Know the lower numbered key (it's may be `1`, `0` or `-1`, etc);
3. Know the higher numbered key (can be *any* number)

Comment: `Object.keys(obj)` and then some filtering

Comment: `Object.keys()`? Conditions ? Or `.filter` ?

Comment: what you have tried??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use [`Object.keys`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/key) for the keys and the filter it with [`Array#filter`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) and [`isFinite`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/isFinite) and apply [`Math.min`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/min) and [`Math.max`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/max)

```js
var obj = {
        foo: 'foo val',
        bar1: 'bar1 val',
        1: 'one',
        2: 'two',
        99: 'ninety nine',
        1024: 'one thousand and twenty four'
    },
    keys = Object.keys(obj),
    numbered = keys.filter(isFinite),
    min = Math.min.apply(null, numbered),
    max = Math.max.apply(null, numbered);

console.log(keys);
console.log(numbered);
console.log(min);
console.log(max);
```

Comment: Nice and pretty. `isFinite` is what I'm looking for

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
var obj = {
    foo: 'foo val',
    bar1: 'bar1 val',
    1: 'one',
    2: 'two',
    99: 'ninety nine',
    1024: 'one thousand and twenty four'
};

console.log(get_numbered_keys(obj))

function get_numbered_keys(obj) {
    return Object.keys(obj)
        .filter(function(key) {
            return !isNaN(key)
        })
        .map(function(key) {
            return parseInt(key)
        })
        .sort(function(a, b) {
            return a - b;
    })
}
```

Also made a fiddle for you: https://jsfiddle.net/2d1bc5tm/

The resulting list is conveniently sorted so you can get the lowest and highest by:

```
var sorted_int_list = get_numbered_keys(obj)

var min = sorted_int_list[0] // gets the first element in array
var max = sorted_int_list.slice(-1)[0] // gets the last element in array
```